# C# accessing anArraylist of floats

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am trying to solve a trivial problem:
Imagine 1440 temperature measurements per day per month.

"int Day[31]float Temp[1440]".

The Microsoft documentation and all else I found has something like:

```
float[][] jaggedArray =
{
    new float[] { 88.3F, 33.9F, 55.4F,  99.9F },
    new float[] { 1.1F, 3F, 5F,  9.9F },
    new float[] { 1F, 3F, 5F,  9F }
};
```

Now I can access any element with

```
float result = jaggedArray[2][1];
```

So far so good.

The disadvantage is that I have to size and initialize the array to start with and
the data sets might not have the same size. (not every month has 30 days)

So I thought that using an Arraylist of an ArrayList would be a good idea.

```
            ArrayList valueSet1= new ArrayList();
            ArrayList valueSet2 = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList Sets = new ArrayList();

                valueSet1.Add(1.0F);
                valueSet1.Add(2.0F);
                valueSet1.Add(3.0F);
                valueSet1.Add(4.0F);

                valueSet2.Add(5.0F);
                valueSet2.Add(6.0F);
                valueSet2.Add(7.0F);
                valueSet2.Add(8.0F);

                Sets.Add(valueSet1);
                Sets.Add(valueSet2);
```

That works also and in the watch window it looks pretty much the same as the array solution, except for accessing the values does not work:

```
float test= Sets[1][1]; //does not work
```

I also tested a foreach approach with no success:

```
 foreach (var ValueSet in Sets)
            {
              // ValueSet exists here but:
               foreach (var item in ValueSet)  // does not recognize ValueSet 
                {
                    
                }
            }
```

I am stumped for now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `ArrayList` class was useful in 2002 and 2003.  It has fallen into disuse since the release since the release of the .NET Framework's generic classes capabilities in 2005.  If you want a "stretchy" array of floats, you really want to use `List<float>`.  If you want a stretchy array of a stretchy array of floats, use `List<List<float>>`.  But, that's probably not the answer to this question.

Comment: Maybe (simplified) a `List<Dictionary<int, List<float>>>`. In one year, you have a List with 12 Dictionaries, where the Key is the day and the Value is your list of floats.

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to do this, I'd take a completely different tack at it.  I'd have a class that represents a day's worth of measurements.  Then, I'd have a class that represents a month's worth of daily measurements - it would contain a dictionary of daily measurement instances, indexed by the day of the month.

So, some housekeeping to get things started.  I like working symbolically, ...

```
public enum Months
{
    January = 1,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
}
```

Now I can work with `Months.September` instead of `9`.

Now I'll create something that keeps track of the temperature measurements during the day.  I'm going to timestamp each measurement (using a `TimeSpan`).  I'm going to keep track of the measurements in a `Dictionary<TimeSpan, float>` tracking each measurement against the time it was recorded.  First the easy part:

```
public class DailyTemperatureMeasurements : IEnumerable<(TimeSpan time, float temperature)>, IEnumerable<float>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TimeSpan, float> _measurements = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, float>();
    private IEnumerable<float> _enumerableImplementation;

    public void Add(TimeSpan time, float temperature)
    {
        _measurements.Add(time, temperature);
    }

    IEnumerator<float> IEnumerable<float>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var measurement in _measurements)
        {
            yield return measurement.Value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<(TimeSpan time, float temperature)> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var measurement in _measurements)
        {
            yield return (measurement.Key, measurement.Value);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<float>) this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Note that I made the class Enumerable in two ways.  You can enumerate through it and just get all the temperatures for the day (without the time stamp), or you can get *Tuples* that represent time stamp/measurement pairs.  I don't use either of these, but you might find it handy.

Also, because the class is enumerable and has an Add method, you can use *Collection Initialization*.  Again, I don't use this, but you might.

The hard part is getting the values out.  I suspect that you might want to use interpolation to get the best possible estimate of the measurement at a specific time.  I'm too lazy for that, so I pick the one just before the requested time.  Also, though dictionaries often return items in the order that they were added, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class specifically says that the order of enumeration is undefined (so I go through all the values to figure this out).  You may want to look at another way to do this.

So, let's add this function to the `DailyTemperatureMeasurements` class...

```
public float GetMeasurementAt(TimeSpan time)
{
    if (!_measurements.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("There are no measurements registered in this object");
    }

    if (_measurements.ContainsKey(time))
    {
        return _measurements[time];
    }

    //you may want to do interpolation, but I'm keeping it simple
    //find the last measurement before the requested time
    var lastClosestTime = default(TimeSpan);
    foreach (var measurement in _measurements)
    {
        var timeToMeasurement = time - measurement.Key;
        if (timeToMeasurement < time - lastClosestTime && timeToMeasurement > default(TimeSpan))
        {
            lastClosestTime = measurement.Key;
        }
    }

    if (lastClosestTime == default)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    return _measurements[lastClosestTime];
}
```

Now I'm tracking all the measurements for a day.  Let's track them for a month:

As you pointed out, not all months have 31 days.  It gets more complicated than that (February).  We don't want bad data, so I have these two little private workers that I'm going to add to my monthly measurement class:

```
 private static readonly Dictionary<Months, int> MonthLengths = new Dictionary<Months, int>
 {
     {Months.January, 31},
     {Months.February, 28},
     {Months.March, 31},
     {Months.April, 30},
     {Months.May, 31},
     {Months.June, 30},
     {Months.July, 31},
     {Months.August, 31},
     {Months.September, 30},
     {Months.October, 31},
     {Months.November, 30},
     {Months.December, 30},
 };

 private static int GetMonthLength(Months month, int year)
 {
     if (month != Months.February)
     {
         return MonthLengths[month];
     }
     //otherwise, month is February, so...
     if (year % 400 == 0)
     {
         return 29;
     }

     if (year % 100 == 0)
     {
         return 28;
     }

     if (year % 4 == 0)
     {
         return 29;
     }

     return 28;
 }
```

This way, if someone tries to add data for the 31st of April or the 29th of February, 2100, I can throw an exception.

Keeping track of monthly measurements is actually quite simple:

```
public class TemperatureMeasurements
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, DailyTemperatureMeasurements> _dailyMeasurements = new Dictionary<int, DailyTemperatureMeasurements>();

    public TemperatureMeasurements(int year, Months month)
    {
        //you may want to sanity check the year value (no years less than now, no years greater than 2500) - maybe
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
    }

    public int Year { get; }
    public Months Month { get; }

    public void Add(int day, TimeSpan time, float measurement)
    {
        if (day < 1 || day > GetMonthLength(Month, Year))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof (day), "Day value must be within range for month: {_month}");
        }

        if (!_dailyMeasurements.ContainsKey(day))
        {
            _dailyMeasurements.Add(day, new DailyTemperatureMeasurements());
        }

        _dailyMeasurements[day].Add(time, measurement);
    }

    public void Add(TimeSpan time, float measurement)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var monthToday = (Months)now.Month;
        if (monthToday != Month)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"This overload of {nameof(Add)} can only be used with today's date is within the month associated with this {nameof(TemperatureMeasurements)} instance ");
        }

        var dayToday = now.Day;
        Add(dayToday, time, measurement);
    }

    public void Add(float measurement)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        Add(now, measurement);
    }

    public float GetMeasurementAt(int day, TimeSpan time)
    {
        if (!_dailyMeasurements.ContainsKey(day))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(day), "No measurements for {Month} {day} have been recorded");
        }

        return _dailyMeasurements[day].GetMeasurementAt(time);
    }

    //This is where that MonthLengths dictionary and GetMonthLengths function go
}
```

You need to provide the month and year that one of these will be used for (so that the correctly number of days in a month can be calculated).

The data is kept in a dictionary, where the key is the day of the month (1..*[number of days in the month]*), and the value is a `DailyTemperatureMeasurements` (the class we create earlier) instance.

You can add data several ways:

- You can specify the day of the month, the time and the measurement
  `void Add(int day, TimeSpan time, float measurement)`
- You can specify just the time and the measurements (it assumes you mean today)
  `void Add(TimeSpan time, float measurement)`
- You can just specify the measurement (it assumes you mean today and now for the day and time)
  `void Add(float measurement)`

To get a value, you call `GetMeasurementAt`, passing the day of the month and the time.  It delegates the call to the appropriate `DailyTemperatureMeasurements` for the requested day.

This code is *very lightly tested*.  You are going to want to test it more.  It should make recording measurements easier.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, there are better options now than the ArrayList.

If you still want to go with it though, you probably want to do this:

```
float x = (float)((ArrayList)Sets[1])[1];
```

or

```
foreach (ArrayList list in Sets)
    foreach (float y in list)
        MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());
```

The ArrayList has "objects" inside and you need to explicitly convert them.

Comment: To everybody: Thanks a lot!!!  I will have to digest this in the next days or weekend!